# CSS : Breaking a row in a table

Tags: css

I set up a table with a certain size but I want to not go over the size so it dropped a row instead [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9smi.png)

Css:

```
    #PPP {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width:500px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to manage overflow in your text using the overflow command in css. This affects what happens to text when it goes past the box. For example, you could use this to include a scroll.

```
overflow: scroll;
```